# Can I use project settings of a VS Code workspace folder when opening a subdirectory of it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I am working in a large project, sometimes I like to open just a sub-directory in visual studio code so my file tree is easier to navigate. However, the workspace settings are saved in a `.vscode` folder in the root directory of the project.

Is it possible to automatically load the projects workspace settings into `vscode` when I open `vscode` from a sub-directory of the projects root directory?

Comment: Currently, the simplest solution would be to link the .vscode folder to the subdirectories, but I wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: Maybe you should look towards [multi-root workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no.

Workarounds:

- Define symlinks in those subdirectories linking to the "real" workspace folder's `.vscode` directory. (this will cause issues if you use paths in the workspace settings that are intended refer to things relative to the "real" workspace folder)
- Use a multi-root workspace and define the settings attached to the workspace's `.code-workspace` file, and just edit the `"folders"` field to whichever subdirectory you want to focus on. (same issues as the symlink approach).
- Use the `folders.exclude` setting to exclude things you don't want to see at the moment. You can have multiple copies of modifications to this setting and just un-comment-out the one you want to be active at some given time. (this can result in thrashy changes in git history if you stage your workspace settings files to revision control unless you intentionally avoid it before staging changes for commit).

You might be interested in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/111884 and/or https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/15909 <sup><sub>[You can show your support for the issue ticket by giving a thumbs up reaction to the issue. But please *don't* make a "me too" comment.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup>